# No JTA UserTransaction available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' 

Tags: java, spring, jboss5.x

I have encountered a strange problem with spring transaction. My application uses Spring with EJBs. The EJBs also invoke Spring service classes annotated with `@Transaction`. I have used Spring `JtaTransactionManager` for transaction management. The application is packaged as an EAR file and is deployed on jboss5.0 and it works fine. But when I instruct jboss to use separate classloader for each EAR application, spring initialization gives error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
   with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource 
   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No JTA UserTransaction 
   available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' or 
   'transactionManager' or 'transactionManagerName'
```

Why initialization of Spring is not successful?

Thanks

Comment: What setting did you change in JBoss?

Comment: I modified ear-deployer-jboss-beans.xml file under "deployers" directory to set property "isolated" to true.

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
```

on a configuration class where you hold your config bean

that worked for me when i had that issue , 
maybe you will need other platform specific implementation of the transaction manager , but this is a good place to start.

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
    return txManager;
}
```

Comment: I'm having similar issue when deploying sboot app in IBM WAS, will check fi this works.

Comment: Migrated couple of healthcare system projects away from IBMWAS to simple sboot. RIP to ibmwas -- ibm even sold it to HCL! Huh.